# The pipe 'searchfilter' could not be found

Tags: angular, ionic3, angular5, ionic4

I have custom Pipe and using ionic 4

```
 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
The pipe 'searchfilter' could not be found ("
  </ul>
   -->
  <ion-card class="card-ios" *ngFor="let[ERROR ->] row of shopList | searchfilter : query">
    <ion-item>
```

1. AppModule.ts

   ```
   import { SearchfilterPipe } from './pipes/search/searchfilter.pipe';

   @NgModule({declarations: [SearchfilterPipe])
   ```
2. Searchfilter.Pipe.ts

   ```
   import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

   @Pipe({
       name: 'searchfilter'
   })
   export class SearchfilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

       transform(value: any, query: string): any {
           return null;
       }

   }
   ```
3. HTML

   ```
   *ngFor="let row of shopList | searchfilter : query"
   ```

Comment: Add the Pipe to the module that declares the component you're trying to use it in. That said, the Angular devs advise *against* using a pipe for filtering https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe

Answer (score 1):

You also need to export your pipe in app.module.ts.
like this:

```
import { SearchfilterPipe } from './pipes/search/searchfilter.pipe';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [SearchfilterPipe],
    exports: [SearchfilterPipe]
)
```

I hope this will help you.